# Visual Basic Excel: Copying text as text

Tags: excel, vba

I am doing

```
Cells(101, 50).Value = Cells(100, 50).Value
```

and there is "001234" in Cells(100,50).

Issue is that the Cells(101,50) is getting 1234 after the statement executes.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Another way

```
Sub Sample()
    Cells(101, 50).Formula = "=TEXT(" & Cells(100, 50).Value & ",""000000"")"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Cells(101,50).Value = "'" & Cells(100,50).Value
```

Or change the format of your target cell to Text

Comment: It won't be visible on the worksheet. The ' character will tell Excel to treat whatever follows the ' as text, and not a number. If you want the cell to deal with it as a number, but still have the zeros in front of it then you'll need to format the cell with a custom format of '000000'

Comment: ok Thank you I think it worked. I accidentally deleted my previous comment. It was "I don't want that "'" in the front and how to set the format of the cell to text programatically". Thanks KFleschner

Comment: I do not know how to accept answer. I tried clicking that triangle on the top of that 0 and it won't let me(It is telling that I should have reputation 15 to do it.)